# Excel: Strange interaction between drop down lists, protected sheets, and hiding rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a strange interaction between a protected worksheet in excel and my dropdown list. The dropdown list, at the top of the sheet, changes the rows that are visible based on the selection the user chooses. Everything works fine when the sheet is unprotected, but when opening the sheet in protected mode everything gets strange. When I select an option on the dropdown, it shows the correct rows, but the next time I try to change the dropdown, the dropdown options either appear at a different area, or are inverted. I will post screenshots below to better explain.

First picture; no option selected; worksheet protected

[image]

Second picture; first option selected, dropdown list goes up; worksheet protected
[image]

Third picture; Third option selected; Dropdown list maps to the bottom section instead, which isn't even a dropdown list cell. Worksheet still protected.[image]

Fourth picture, third option selected, everything is normal; worksheet UNprotected.
[image]

My code is simple. I will post an example of it.

```
Sub ProtectSheetsNoPassword()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, _
                Contents:=True, _
                Scenarios:=False, _
                AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
                AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
                AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
                AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
                AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
                AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
                AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
                AllowSorting:=False, _
                AllowFiltering:=False, _
                AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
    'ws.Unprotect 'Uncomment if you want to unprotect the sheets
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'This is the code that shows or hides specific rows based on the type selected
If Range("B1") = "1" Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("1:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Rows("19:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else If Range("B1") = "2" Then
.......So on so forth
```

I have no idea what's happening here. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Would be more useful to post your code.

Comment: It would also be most helpful to post images with some dummy data to make it easier to see exactly what's happening. Obviously you cannot post the real data for privacy reasons, so make up some fun stuff!

Comment: The data is irrelevant, honestly. It is basic; If DDL-1 is selected, show rows A-B, hide rows C-Z. If DDL-2 is selected, show rows C-D, Hide A-B, D-Z. So on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. When protecting my worksheet, I needed to check the "edit objects" box to fix the issue. Makes sense, if you think of Dropdown lists as objects I suppose. I am not sure what logic is there to make it act so strangely though.